# Is computation of a given operation infinitely multiply realizable 'computationally-speaking'?

Tags: turing-machines, information-theory, philosophy

This is a somewhat philosophical question, but I would like to know if there is a hard answer. Also, please excuse my likely unconventional terminology here, this is not my field of expertise.

Multiply Realizable: can be instantiated in many different ways but still be the same system. Example, command line Chess is still chess if written in Python or C.

Infinitely Multiply Realizable: can be instantiated in an infinite number of ways.

**Clarification:** I am not talking about the multiple realizability of a computation in different media (e.g. the fact that a Turing machine can be made of anything). Instead, I am asking the following:

**Main Question:**

- For a given type of computation (addition of two integers for example) is there one fundamental or definitive way of expressing that computation so that every other way of doing it could be reduced to that fundamental way?

**Example:**

For some operation $A$ (e.g. 'add two integers') is there an infinite set of computations/algorithms which count as $A$?
(We can say an operation counts as $A$ if and only if it has exactly the same results as 'add two integers' for all inputs)

Let's keep using "add two integers" as an example. We might do:

```
   0101   (5 in binary)
 + 0101   (5 in binary)
 --------
  1010    (10 in binary)
```

via a 'carry into the column/carry out of the column' binary addition algorithm. However, it seems like we could equally *still be doing $A$* if we did another algorithm instead like using XOR modulo 2 and counting the number of times we go through the modulus, or representing a length and extending it, or via summing analog waves or something. Whatever the operation or algorithm, if it satisfies the conditions for $A$ it seems to count as addition.

If there truly are an infinite number of ways to 'do $A$' then at least some computations are multiply realizable in this sense.

**Other Questions:**

- Is this an incorrect understanding?
- Where can I read more on this topic?

Comment: What is your question?  Please make sure to state the question in the body of your post.  The title is not just the first sentence of your post -- it is a short description.  I don't see a question in the body of your post, the first question I see is "Another way of asking the question is:", but that's before I have seen the first way of asking the question.

Comment: I don't know what "infinitely multiply realizable" means.  I don't know what it means for an algorithm to "count as A".  Please [edit] your post to state the question clearly.  Define all non-standard terms.  It might help to specify what computation you are trying to do in standard format, e.g., list the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output, or specify its behavior mathematically.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you consider two algorithms to be different, vs the same?  This affects how you count how many different algorithms there are to do something.

Comment: Thanks for your patient feedback. I have updated the question.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on what you mean by "reduced to that fundamental way" (that sounds like it could be a matter of opinion) or "count as A".  CS is a technical subject -- I don't think you have a well-defined, answerable question about CS until you can define those terms.  Otherwise we'll just be stuck arguing about definitions, which probably isn't terribly productive (or is more for philosophy than CS).

Comment: Another way to think about it -- what difference would it make if the answer was yes or if it was no?  What concrete problem are you facing that you need to solve?  (Per our [help/dont-ask], the site is only for "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".)

Comment: It is typical (I think) for every computable function to have infinitely many representations in most computational systems (Turing machines, lambda calculus, partial recursive functions, Python, ...). This is because, among other reasons, you can insert extra operations that don't meaningfully affect the answer, but make the computational details slightly different. That would be a precise statement that might answer your question.

Comment: @DanDoel, I agree with that. However, is there any way to determinately say that one representation of the computation is the minimally viable one for that computation (let's say the Turning machine's 'add two int')?

That would mean, precisely, that all other representations of 'add two int' could be expressed mathematically as instances of the Turing machines representation of 'add two int'. 

Does "being the same computation" simply come down to different representations being "functionally equivalent" (representations having exactly the same outputs for all the same inputs)?

Comment: @claytongroth The minimal TM computing something isn't computable. It might be better to formulate this question using circuits (for which this is computable, but not efficiently as far as we know).